# My code keeps iterating at the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

Please im building a simple a bid auction application using pytho.

however it kept iterating a the while loop

meawhile there is another condition after the while loop.

Please help.

Thank you

```
import os


print ("Welcome To The Bid Auction")
another_bid='yes'

#create an empty dict to store all bids
bids={}

while another_bid=="yes":

   bidder_name=input ( str("Enter Bidder Name:"))

   bid_price= float(input("Enter Bid Amount"))
 
#add input to dict   

bids[bidder_name]= bid_price 

#clear screen for another input       

another_bid= input (" Is there another bidder? Yes or No__:").lower()
if another_bid=='yes':
    os.system("cls")
    bidder_name=input ("Enter Bidder Name:")

    bid_price= float(input("Enter Bid Amount"))


#  getting the highest bid
max_bid=max(bids.values())
print(f"max bid amount is:""{max_bid}")
highest_bidders =[key for key, value in bids.items() if value==max_bid]
highest_bidder="".join(highest_bidders)
print (f'string: {highest_bidder}')
print (f'Thank you all for participating, the winner is {highest_bidder}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the `another_bid`, to solve this move code below inside the while block, and `break` the `while` loop when the `another_bid` equals to `no`.

```
another_bid= input (" Is there another bidder? Yes or No__:").lower()
if another_bid=='yes':
    os.system("cls")
    bidder_name=input ("Enter Bidder Name:")
    bid_price= float(input("Enter Bid Amount"))
```

Also there is no need to take input again, and you can also remove the `str` method inside `input` function.

```
while another_bid=="yes":
   bidder_name = input("Enter Bidder Name:")
   bid_price = float(input("Enter Bid Amount"))

   bids[bidder_name]= bid_price 

   another_bid= input ("Is there another bidder? Yes or No__:").lower()
   if another_bid=='yes':
      os.system("cls")
   else:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop `while another_bid=="yes":`, there is no statement that could change `another_bid` to false. While loops go forever if the condition is always true. I would suggest adding:

```
if (bidder_name == "end"):
     another_bid = "no"
```

to the end of the while loop. You can change `"end"` to something else, but the user needs a way to tell the program to stop looping.